# How to put tooltip message on fields rather than labels

Tags: tooltip, field, message, odoo

Good morning, My question, please is how can we put help tooltip message on fields rather than labels (which is by default) so that when the user put the cursor n the textfield the tooltip message appears.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the tooltip for the field as

```
'empty_acc': fields.boolean('Empty Accounts ? ', help='Check if you want to display Accounts with 0 balance too.'),
```

Where "Check if you want to display Accounts with 0 balance too." will be shown when the user put the cursor on the field empty_acc. But i think we wont be able to show the tooltip when the cursor is on the text field.

Comment: This help message will appear when the cursor will be on the label 'Empty Accounts', but I want the message appearing when the cursor is on the checkbox itself in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no label for the field, then help tooltip message will be shown for the text field. you can see an example in customer's address

Comment: good to know even if it wasn't exactly what i am looking for. Thx